# Set Mail app to show mail subject on top instead of sender

Tags: windows-10, email-client

In the Mail app's list view, I would like to view the mail's subject on top for each item. The default is showing the senders of the mail conversation on top, then the subject with smaller font, then the content brief.

In the Outlook app, I used to be able to set this order. Is it somehow possible for Mail?

I looked in all the options of the app and the help it linked to. Also googled some, but not exactly sure what I'm supposed to search for to reduce irrelevant results.

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried so far?

Comment: I tried looking through all the options in the app and browsed the help for it. Also tried googling the problem, but I'm not even sure how these components of the app are called to perform an accurate search.

Comment: Please add these details to your question by using the [edit] link.